# NSCoding line never returns and runs forever

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

One of my classes in my iOS app implements NSCoding. It saves this object to a file when it is changed and loads from it when the app is opened. The app unfortunately won't start now and if I pause execution in Xcode, no matter when I pause it, the main thread is trying to execute `decodeObjectForKey` after calling `initWithCoder`.

I know the file is not empty and the app doesn't crash when I'm debugging. It does crash when I open it straight from my device, most likely because the start up was taking so long. Leading up to this the storage on my device was empty, but I have since freed up space.

Is it best to assume that the saved object is corrupt? If so how should I handle this in the future? How can I identify a file as being corrupt?

```
NSData *myEncodedObject = [MPSettings dataForKey:@"songCache"];
sharedInstance = (SongManager *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myEncodedObject]; //<------- Stuck on this
```

//Calls this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    if((self = [super init])){
        //decode properties, other class vars
        allSongs = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"allSongs"];
        _groupByAlbum = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groupByAlbum"];
        _groupByAlbumx = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groupByAlbumx"];
        _groupByArtist = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groupByArtist"];
        _groupByArtistx = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groupByArtistx"];
        playlists = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"playlists"];
        _lastUpdated = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lastUpdatedArray"]; //<--- STUCK HERE
        if(_lastUpdated == nil){
            _lastUpdated = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:[allSongs mutableCopy] forKey:@"allSongs"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_groupByAlbum forKey:@"groupByAlbum"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_groupByAlbumx forKey:@"groupByAlbumx"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_groupByArtist forKey:@"groupByArtist"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_groupByArtistx forKey:@"groupByArtistx"];
    [encoder encodeObject:playlists forKey:@"playlists"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_lastUpdated forKey:@"lastUpdatedArray"];
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It seems something was wrong with the music library on my phone. The NSCoding method was stopped on a line that was retrieving an array of MPMediaItems or songs. After restarting the device, it started functioning properly again.

Comment: no idea. can you provide the code for your class that's having this issue?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Could you post your `encodeWithCoder:` method? Also, what kind of objects does your `_lastUpdated` array contain? Do those objects also implement the `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: @DrBeardface My `_lastUpdated ` includes an array of MPMediaItems. I would assume they do because Apple implemented them and this app has been working for so long.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's not calling an error at all. I could leave my device for an hour and it would still be on the launch screen. It's like it's not even doing anything...

Comment: Hmm.. I think it is getting hung up waiting on those MPMediaItem objects to load. I tried running a MPMediaQuery and it never returned items.

Comment: Guess that confirms my suspicion. Something is wrong with the iTunes Music Library on the device as Apple's music app won't even launch. The `_lastUpdatedArray` depends on MPMediaItems which are not getting loaded.

Comment: There's a semaphore wait at the top of your stack.  I think you have the main thread and another both waiting for each other.   Review your GCD code... all we can see is one cropped off dispatch_async